# How to change one color for another?, in Fireworks CS6

Tags: adobe-fireworks, color-conversion

Using Adobe Fireworks CS6, if you want to use this image

[image]

but Instead of the balck color I want that the image use the #F1A340 color (close to orange)

How could I do this?. I try Adding FILTERS OF PHOTOSHOP / COLORS (solaping) , but the results are not good enough as you can see in the next image, because the number are less legible and the image isn´t as clear as the first one.
Some white parts are in the close to orange image in #F1A340 color.

What is the rigth choice to do this change of color (black - #F1A340)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, because your image is black and white you can use it as a mask.

- Invert the image to make the lines white `(Filters / Adjust Color / Invert)`
- Copy it.
- Make a rectangle with the colour you want.
- Click the `Add Mask` button in the Layers panel.
- Paste the image in.

Now you can make the canvas the colour you want, and even add a drop shadow or other effect if you want to help the lines stand out.

[image: Steps for using an image as a mask]